# Shapefile straight line feature appearing as arcs at different zoom levels

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line

I have a Shapefile that contains sanitary sewer pipe sections. ArcGIS and AutoCAD Map both display all of the pipe segments as straight lines. However, when displayed in QGIS, depending on the zoom level, some of the pipe segments will appear as arcs.

Pipe as Arc
[image: Pipe as Arc]

Pipe as Straight Line
[image: Pipe as line]

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: could it be using the `arrow` style (without arrow head), with the `curve` option?